# Create magnified call-out loupe effect on image

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I'm trying to create a Mathematica `Manipulate` that generates a graphical call-out using a 'loupe'-style or magnifying glass enlarger - a possible solution is shown in this mock-up:
[image: loupe]

The idea is that you can move the focus (a point on the source image, I suppose), and see the enlarged result inside the 'loupe' or magnifying glass. Variable enlargement would be needed as well. It could be a rectangular loupe, I suppose, but circles would be cool.

This style of image is generally recommended because it allows people to see details and the context of those details.

This is what I've managed to do so far:

```
m = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 300];
imageData = ImageData[m, DataReversed -> True];
Manipulate[
 Grid[
  {{
    Graphics[{
      Raster[imageData, {{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[m]}], Point[pt]}, 
     ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[m]],
    Graphics[{Raster[imageData, {{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[m]}], 
      Disk[pt, 5]}, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[m]]
    }}],
 {{pt, {200, 200}}, Locator}]
```

[image: loupe first attempt]

The dot in the right image follows the left image.

I can't see how to make the circular shape or to make it track the point or to add a magnifying option.

Help or clues appreciated!

### Edit

I thought all these answers were great and it's a pity I can't accept them all... :( I noticed that with some of the solutions (@szabolcs, @simon) the image seems to be transformed and looks better/smoother than it really is, whereas the other solutions show the pixels themselves. Both approaches are useful in their own way, depending on whether you're trying to point out the pixel structure or the image content.

Comment: The pasted code does not scan (backslashes)...

Comment: can your loupe be rectangular?

Comment: @YvesKlett didn't notice those when i pasted. Sorry!

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov rectangular would work but not quite as cool :)

Comment: Related: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PictureInspector/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A slight modification of Heike's answer, uses the `Locator` as the lens itself:

```
With[{m=ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage","Mandrill"}],300],rad=50},
 Manipulate[Image[m,ImageSize->300],{{pt,{200,200}},Locator,
  Appearance->SetAlphaChannel[ImageResize[
   ImageTrim[ImagePad[m,50],{{50,50}+Round[pt]-rad/mag,{50,50}+Round[pt]+rad/mag}],
   {{2 rad},{2 rad}}],Image[DiskMatrix[rad-1,2 rad]]]},{{mag,5,"Magnification"},1,15}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics][image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 23):

Here's my implementation.  It is based on textures, so it is very responsive.

```
loupe[img_?ImageQ, r_:0.2] :=
 With[
  {circle = N@Table[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 2 Pi/20, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}],
   s = 1/Divide @@ ImageDimensions[img]
   },
  Deploy@DynamicModule[{pos = {0.5, 0.5}, mag = 3},
    Column[{
      Row[{Slider[Dynamic[mag], {1, 10}], Spacer[10], Dynamic[mag]}],
      Graphics[
       {{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm@Directive[Thick, Black], 
         Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, s}]}, 
        Raster[ImageData[img, DataReversed -> True], {{0, 0}, {1, s}}],

        Thick, Dynamic@Line[{pos, pos + {0, -r}}], 
        Dynamic@Line[{pos, pos + {r, 0}}],

        Dynamic[
          {Texture[img], 
           Polygon[# + pos + {r, -r} & /@ (r circle), 
             VertexTextureCoordinates -> ((#/{1, s}) & /@ (# + pos &) /@ (r circle/mag))]}],

        Dynamic@Circle[pos + {r, -r}, r],

        Dynamic@Locator@Dynamic[pos]},
       ImageSize -> 450, PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 2 r}, {2 r, 0}}
       ]
      }]
    ]
  ]
```

Just pass any image to the `loupe` function:

```
loupe[ExampleData[{"TestImage","Mandrill"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice! +1
Interesting effect when the locator crosses the right edge of the image.

Comment: @Eli that effect could be removed, but I was lazy ... maybe later.

Answer (score 19):

Here's one way. Note that it does rely heavily on functions that are new in version 8, so it won't work on older versions of Mathematica.

```
With[{m = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 300], rad = 50},
 Manipulate[Grid[{{Image[m, ImageSize -> 300],
     SetAlphaChannel[
      ImageResize[
       ImageTrim[
        ImagePad[m, 50], {{50, 50} + Round[pt] - rad/mag, {50, 50} + Round[pt] + rad/mag}], 
       {{2 rad}, {2 rad}}], 
      Image[DiskMatrix[rad - 1, 2 rad]]]}}],
  {{pt, {200, 200}}, Locator},
  {{mag, 1, "Magnification"}, 1, 15}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to share a code which controls the magnification by mouse:

```
m = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 300];
imageData = ImageData[m, DataReversed -> True];

Module[{magnifMin = 1, magnifMax = 30, rMin = 5, rMax = 50, arrowpos = {400, 150}},
       DynamicModule[{pt = {100, 100}, r = 10, magnif = 10,
                      ptInt, ptOld, ptNew},
            ptInt = Round[pt];
            EventHandler[

              (* the main part *)
               Grid[{{

                    Graphics[{
                        Raster[imageData, {{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[m]}],
                        EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[],
                        Dynamic@Circle[pt, r],
                        Black, Thick,
                        Dynamic@Line[{arrowpos, pt + r Normalize[arrowpos - pt]}]
                             },
                       ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> None],

                    Overlay[{Graphics[{
                                    Raster[
                                        Dynamic@imageData[[
                                            ptInt[[2]] - r ;; ptInt[[2]] + r,
                                            ptInt[[1]] - r ;; ptInt[[1]] + r]],
                                          {{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[m]}]
                                      }, ImageSize -> Dynamic[2 r magnif]],
                             Graphics[{
                                    Black, Thickness[.06], Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
                                    White, Thickness[1], Circle[{0, 0}, 2]},
                                    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
                                    ImageSize -> Dynamic[2 r magnif]]
                            }]
                  }}, Spacings -> 0],
              (* control variables for EventHandler *)
               {
                "MouseDown" :> If[CurrentValue["ModifierKeys"],
                                  ptNew = MousePosition[ ],
                                  pt = Round@MousePosition["Graphics"]
                                 ],

                "MouseDragged" :> If[CurrentValue["ControlKey"],
                                     ptOld = ptNew;
                                     ptNew = MousePosition[ ];
                                     Piecewise[{
                                         {magnif = Min[1.1 magnif, magnifMax],
                                          (ptNew - ptOld)[[2]] < 0},
                                         {magnif = Max[0.9 magnif, magnifMin],
                                          (ptNew - ptOld)[[2]] > 0}
                                        }, None],

                                     If[CurrentValue["ShiftKey"],
                                        ptOld = ptNew;
                                        ptNew = MousePosition[ ];
                                        Piecewise[{
                                            {r = Min[r + 1, rMax],
                                             (ptNew - ptOld)[[1]] > 0},
                                            {r = Max[r - 1, rMin],
                                             (ptNew - ptOld)[[1]] < 0}
                                           }, None],

                                        pt = MousePosition["Graphics"];
                                        pt = {Min[300 - r, Max[r + 1, pt[[1]]]], 
                                              Min[300 - r, Max[r + 1, pt[[2]]]]};
                                        ptInt = Round[pt]]
                                   ]
               }
         ]]
     ]
```

[image]

You can use left-click/drag to select the magnifying region, or while the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed, dragging the mouse up/down to adjust magnification, or while the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed, dragging the mouse left/right to adjust the size of the magnifying region.

Wish this a useful supplement for the above answers.

**Edit:**

Add the circle frame (implemented by `Overlay`) and the point line.

Comment: Looks promising, but the code you have up there doesn't execute by itself. Can you add the extra bits?

Comment: @EliLansey Sorry for being lazy :) The two lines which initialize the `imageData` have been added.

Comment: Nifty! I find if I zoom in too much I start getting `Part::partd: "Part specification 0[[1]] is longer than depth of object."` errors.

Comment: @EliLansey It seems like because the `MousePosition["Graphics"]` returns unexpected value when the mouse is outside of the graphics. I have corrected it just now.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an in-place magnifier, using `ImageTransformation` which allows for quite compact code:

```
With[{m = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 300]}, 
 Manipulate[
  ImageTransformation[m, 
   p + (# - p)/(1 + (mag - 1) UnitStep[radius - Norm[# - p]]) &, DataRange -> Full]
, {mag, 1, 5}, {radius, 20, 100}, {{p, {150, 150}}, Locator}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice! +1