# How can I create a glass distortion effect in an image?

Tags: image-processing, image, algorithm, optics

I'd like to overlay a glass jar onto an image with realistic light bending. Can anyone think of a way to automate this effect? Perhaps this can be done with the raytracing package [Rayica / Optica](http://www.opticasoftware.com/)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [A similar question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8673)

Comment: @J.M. - Seems completely different to me. That one is about a partial enlargement, this one about refraction.

Comment: If you're looking for ray tracing solutions, then there isn't really much to be said for Mathematica here. I would use Blender instead.

Comment: Ok, then can some simpler distorting function be used?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**================= UPDATE ======================**

Due to @halirutan comment I'll add a note on realism. First of all pure water and clouds are not the best subject to simulate reflecations because they have **fractal structure** - meaning they tend to appear the same on different magnification scales. So it is hard to give impression to a human eye of refraction effect.

I suggest introducing some **non-fractal elements**, like the one below. Also @halirutan is right slight offset of horizon line from vertical my enhance effect perception. This is the new app with vertical and horizontal scales added. Code is below the app. (*I do not give URL for **o** variable - please find your own source.*)

[image]

I also realized we can do magnifying or metaphorical effects like the one below:

[image]

```
o = ImageResize[Import[ (* use your own source *) ], 900];

j = ImageResize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KISh.jpg"], 500];

Manipulate[i1 = ImageMultiply[ImageResize[#, {h, v} ImageDimensions[#]] &@o,
 ImageAdjust[j, {0, 0, g}]];
 mask = Blur[Binarize[ImageMultiply[i1, RegionBinarize[j, {{10, 10}}, 0.1]], .0], 4];
 Image[ImageAdd[Blur[ImageMultiply[o, mask], b], 
   ImageMultiply[i1, ColorNegate@mask]], ImageSize -> 400]
 , {{g, 3, "jar opacity"}, .1, 10}
 , {{h, .85, "horizontal refraction"}, .5, 1.5}
 , {{v, .9, "vertical refraction"}, .875, 1.5}
 , {{b, 7, "background blur"}, 0, 10}, FrameMargins -> 0, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

**================= ORIGINAL POST ======================**

Some public ocean image and your jar:

```
o = ImageResize[Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Clouds_\
over_the_Atlantic_Ocean.jpg"], 900];

j = ImageResize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KISh.jpg"], 500];
```

Now this line does:

- Compression image re-sizing to simulate refraction effect
- Gamma correction of jar to change its opacity
- `ImageMultiply` for nice overlaying of images

Here you go:

```
i1=ImageMultiply[ImageResize[#, {.5, 1} ImageDimensions[#]] &@o,ImageAdjust[j, {0, 0, 5}]]
```

[image]

This creates mask:

```
mask = Blur[Binarize[ImageMultiply[i1, RegionBinarize[j, {{10, 10}}, 0.1]], .0], 3]
```

[image]

Blur original image and use mask to cut a hole. Then use mask to create filler for the hole:

```
{Blur[ImageMultiply[o, mask], 5], ImageMultiply[i1, ColorNegate@mask]}
```

[image]

Finally fill the hole with `ImageAdd` and make an app:

```
Manipulate[i1 = ImageMultiply[ImageResize[#, {r, 1} ImageDimensions[#]] &@o, 
   ImageAdjust[j, {0, 0, g}]];
 mask = Blur[Binarize[ImageMultiply[i1, RegionBinarize[j, {{10, 10}}, 0.1]], .0], 4];
 Image[ImageAdd[Blur[ImageMultiply[o, mask], b], 
   ImageMultiply[i1, ColorNegate@mask]], ImageSize -> 400]
 , {{g, 3, "jar opacity"}, .1, 10}
 , {{r, .6, "refraction"}, .5, 1.5}
 , {{b, 7, "background blur"}, 0, 10}, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Your given glass jar image has slight shadow against white background which is a usual thing that Photoshop artists add. A photo without the shadow would blend with ocean background better. There is also another `Blur` function for the mask that you can control to blend to your taste.

Comment: +Masterful Lesson in image processing. Thanks.

Comment: +1 I think it's better to scale in both direction so that the horizon-line is shifted. This gives in my opinion a more realistic refraction fake. [See here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VrOZf.png)

Comment: @halirutan good point. I updated the post.

Comment: In case someone wants the original image: http://wallpaperswide.com/bungalows_on_the_ocean-wallpapers.html

Comment: @DavidCarraher Thank you David ;-)

Answer (score 28):

This is more of an add-on to Vitaliy's excellent answer, than a completely new approach. I wanted to try to simulate some of the image distortion that would be seen at the jar walls. A simple (though utterly wrong in a physics sense) way to do this is to make the demagnification vary according to the jar image intensity.

Load a picture and the jar image, and pad the jar image to match the picture size.

```
image = Import["sunset.jpg"];
jar = ImageResize[Import["2KISh.jpg"], 750];
jar = ImageCrop[jar, ImageDimensions@image, Padding -> White];
```

For the fake refraction, I use a grayscale copy of the jar with a gamma adjustment (this amplifies the effect). `ImageTransformation` is used to create the effect, which is a simple magnification whose amplitude is obtained from the `ImageValue` of `jar2`. The variable `p` determines the centre of magnification, in this case it is at the image centre since that is where the jar is.

```
jar2 = ImageAdjust[ColorConvert[jar, "Grayscale"], {0, 0, 2}];
p = Round[ImageDimensions[image]/2];
refract = ImageTransformation[image, p + ImageValue[jar2, #] (# - p) &, DataRange -> Full];
refract = ImageMultiply[refract, jar];
```

To combine the refraction effect with the original image I use Vitaliy's `mask` as an alpha channel to remove everything outside the jar. The final image is then made using `ImageCompose`.

```
mask = ColorNegate@Blur[RegionBinarize[jar, {{10, 10}}, 0.05]];
overlay = SetAlphaChannel[refract, mask];
ImageCompose[Blur[image, 5], overlay]
```

[image]

Comment: @simonwoods I'm impressed! thanks for this addition Simon