# Take part of image under locator

Tags: image-processing

How to create Manipulator with Locator to take part of an image?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8673/create-magnified-call-out-loupe-effect-on-image)

Comment: Good, thanks! But how to avoid padding of croped image?

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your question to include this information... This will also help to avoid this question being closed as a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that Manipulate[] can control the portion of the selected image with a locator is:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
{dR, dC} = ImageDimensions[img];
Manipulate[
  Show[img, 
    ImageTake[img, {dR-50-p[[2]], dR+50-p[[2]]}, {p[[1]]-50,p[[1]] + 50}]], 
{{p, {dR/2, dC/2}}, Locator}]
```

This lets you scan around, zooming into the image. Control the size by the integers inside ImageTake[] (set to 50 here).

Answer (score 2):

Of course, this is completely automatic in version 9. If we `Import` your image and just click on it, we get easy access to a crop tool, as well as others.  It looks something like so:

[image]

Here's the cropped image:

[image]

Comment: that is a nice addition in 9.

Comment: @Elfet Just out of curiosity - why the down vote?