# Using MatrixPlot, how can I dynamically zoom in and out with my mouse?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a MatrixPlot output which I would like to zoom around in, drawing boxes that define a zoom region with my mouse.  These things are all fairly standard in Labview... surely Mathematica must have a similar set of abilities?

For an example matrix, we can write:

```
TestArray = Array[RandomInteger[{0, 1}] &, {100, 100}];
MatrixPlot[TestArray]
```

Comment: Having your `MatrixPlot` done, click once on it and pressing a small orange rectangle at the bottom of the plot, drag it to zoom your plot.  Use simply `RandomInteger[1, {100, 100}]` instead of `Array[RandomInteger[{0, 1}] &, {100, 100}]`.

Comment: @Artes Thanks for the tip about not using Array.  However, I meant being able to use my mouse to define a window within the graphic, which we then clip and zoom to.  Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7142/5

Answer (score 3):

Have you explored the capabilites of `Manipulate` yet?

```
Manipulate[
 MatrixPlot[TestArray,
  Mesh -> m,
  ColorFunction -> cf,
  PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}],
 {xmin, 1, 50, 1}, {ymin, 1, 50, 1},
 {xmax, 51, 100, 1}, {ymax, 51, 100, 1},
 {m, 1, 50},
 {cf, ColorData["Gradients"]}
 ]
```

[image: matrix plot explorer]

Here's a slightly more mouse-y one:

```
coordsToRowColumns[pt_, mag_, w_, h_] := 
 Module[{rmin, cmin, rmax, cmax},
  rmin =  pt[[1]];
  cmin = h - pt[[2]] ;
  rmax = pt[[1]] + mag ;
  cmax = cmin + mag;
  {{cmin, cmax}, {cmin, cmax}}]
TestArray = RandomReal[1, {100, 100}];
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   MatrixPlot[
    TestArray,
    ImageSize  -> 200,
    PlotRangePadding -> 0,
    ColorFunction -> cf],
   MatrixPlot[
    TestArray,
    ImageSize  -> 400,
    PlotRange -> coordsToRowColumns[pt, mag, 100, 100],
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    ColorFunction -> cf
    ]
   }
  ],
 {{pt, {0, 100}} , Locator},
 {{mag, 50, "Magnification"}, 1, 100},
 {cf, ColorData["Gradients"]},
 ControlPlacement -> {Bottom, Top}]
```

[image: zoomy mag thing]

I prefer this kind of view, sometimes, over a simple zoom in/out style. Here, you can see an overview of where you are, so you don't get lost, and you you can change the magnification without changing the location. There's room for improvement, though.

Comment: Actually, I've just been playing around with Manipulate.  However, what I'm really looking to do is to quickly define a zoom region with my mouse.  Could I perhaps click somewhere and then have Manipulate provide me a slidebar to zoom in and out centered on that clicked point?  That seems like it would be within the range of Mathematica's capabilities?

Comment: @uka something similar [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8673/create-magnified-call-out-loupe-effect-on-image) which could be easily adapted. Look up `Locator`s too, for mouse input.