# Magnifying Glass on a Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

Although there is a trick in TEX  [magnifying glass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267829/plot-with-magnifying-glass-with-a-different-plot-in-it) but I want to know is there any function to magnifying glass on a plot with *Mathematica*?

For example for a function as `Sin[x] and at x=Pi/6`

Below, this is just a picture desired from the cited site.
the image got huge unfortunately I don't know how can I change the size of an image here!
[image]

Comment: To my knowledge there is no build-in function for this purpose but you could write one using `Epilog`

Comment: Related: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/InsetPlotMagnifier/

Comment: [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html?q=Inset).

Comment: Related: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8673/862) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7142/862)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Insetting a magnified part of the original `Plot`

A) by adding a new `Plot` of the specified range

```
xPos = Pi/6;
range = 0.2;
f = Sin;
xyMinMax = {{xPos - range, xPos + range}, 
  {f[xPos] - range*GoldenRatio^-1, f[xPos] + range*GoldenRatio^-1}};

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
 Epilog -> {Transparent, EdgeForm[Thick], 
   Rectangle[Sequence @@ Transpose[xyMinMax]], 
   Inset[Plot[f[x], {x, xPos - range, xPos + range}, Frame -> True, 
     Axes -> False, PlotRange -> xyMinMax, ImageSize -> 270], {4., 0.5}]}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: PlotA]

B) by adding a new `Plot` within a `Circle`

```
mf = RegionMember[Disk[{xPos, f[xPos]}, {range, range/GoldenRatio}]]

Show[{Graphics@Circle[{xPos, f[xPos]}, {range, range/GoldenRatio}], 
  Plot[f[x], {x, xPos - range, xPos + range}] /. 
   Graphics[{{{}, {}, {formating__, line_Line}}}, stuff___] :> 
    Graphics[{{{}, {}, {formating, 
        Line[Pick[line[[1]], mf[line[[1]]]]]}}}, stuff]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
 Epilog -> {Transparent, EdgeForm[Thick], 
   Disk[{xPos, f[xPos]}, {range, range/GoldenRatio}], 
   Inset[%, {4.1, 0.5}]}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: PlotB]

C) by adding the `Line` segments within a `Circle` of the original `Plot`

```
Show[{Graphics[{Green, 
    Circle[{xPos, f[xPos]}, {range, range/GoldenRatio}]}],
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}] /. 
   Graphics[{{{}, {}, {formating__, line_Line}}}, stuff___] :> 
    Graphics[{{{}, {}, {formating, 
        Line[Pick[line[[1]], mf[line[[1]]]]]}}}, stuff]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
 Epilog -> {Green, Line[{{xPos + range, f[xPos]}, {3.38, 0.5}}], 
   Transparent, EdgeForm[Green], 
   Disk[{xPos, f[xPos]}, {range, range/GoldenRatio}], 
   Inset[%, {4.1, 0.5}]}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: PlotC]

Comment: Wonderful, It is so good

Answer (score 29):

There are built-in magnifying glasses. However, spontaneously I don't know how to invoke one directly for a `Plot`. Therefore I'm going to demonstrate one way that converts the `Plot` `Graphics` object into an `Image`:

```
Image@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}]
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetRectangleImageSelection"]]
```

[image: ScreenGif]

---

The image ribbon itself is

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "SystemResources", "AttachedImage2D.nb"}]
```

---

One can use, for example, [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) to get a magnified `Plot` at the current [`MousePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MousePosition.html).

```
Plot[Tooltip[Sin[x], 
  Dynamic@Plot[
    Sin[xx], {xx, First@MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}] - 0.1, 
     First@MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}] + 0.1}, Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Background -> None], TooltipDelay -> 0, 
  TooltipStyle -> {Background -> None, CellFrameColor -> None}], {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: TooltipAnimation]

Or use the Get Coordinates tool, which gets activated by selecting the graphics and pressing <kbd>.</kbd>.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> 
    Function[pt, 
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, pt[[1]] - 0.1, pt[[1]] + 0.1}, 
      Background -> White]]}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Comment: Besides so much thanks, But I want to export an unchangeable inset magnified plot which put on the main plot to a "PDF" format!!

Answer (score 18):

This is an interactive zoom that you can use in CDF or notebook. It plots a small x-range around the `MousePosition` as it moves around the main plot and `Inset`s that smaller plot into the main plot.

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] + 0.05 Cos[10 x]


Plot[f[x], {x, 0, π},
 Epilog -> {
   Dynamic[
    With[{xpos = First@MousePosition[{"Graphics", Plot}, {π/2, 0}]},
     Inset[
      Plot[f[x], {x, xpos - 0.1, xpos + 0.1},
       Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Small
       ],
      {0.6, 0.05}, ImageScaled[{0, 0}]
      ]
     ]]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very nice and amazing!!!!

Answer (score 15):

Why not use the mouse cursor? This version shows the zooming frame when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is pressed.

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] + 0.05 Cos[10 x];

DynamicModule[{p},
 Dynamic@MouseAppearance[
   Plot[f[x], {x, 0, Pi}],
   If[CurrentValue@"ControlKey", 
    p = First@MousePosition["Graphics", {0, 0}]; 
    Plot[f[x], {x, p - 0.1, p + 0.1}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> None, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, 
     ImageSize -> 100, Epilog -> {Red, Point@Scaled@{.5, .5}}], 
    Automatic, Automatic]]]
```

[image: zooming]

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know about `MouseAppearance`. +1

Comment: @Edmund And you can use *anything* as a mouse cursor with `MouseAppearance`.

Answer (score 15):

Here is one way, how you can make a [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to dynamically change the magnified area and then use `Setting` to get the `Plot` together with the magnification parts as a static graphics object to be exported.

```
f = Sin;

Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
  Epilog -> {Transparent, EdgeForm[Thick], 
    Disk[pos, {range, range/GoldenRatio}], 
    Inset[Show[{Graphics@Circle[pos, {range, range/GoldenRatio}], 
       Plot[f[x], {x, xPos - range, xPos + range}, 
        RegionFunction -> 
         Function[{x, y}, 
          RegionMember[
           Disk[pos, {range, range/GoldenRatio}], {x, y}]]]}, 
      PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], {4.35, 0.6}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 700], {{range, 0.2}, 0.01, 1}, {{xPos, 1}, None}, {mf, 
  None},
 {{pos, {1, 0.5}}, Locator, Appearance -> None, 
  TrackingFunction -> (pos = #; xPos = pos[[1]]; &)}]
```

[image: ScreenGIF]

Comment: Nice illustration (+1). May be `RegionFunction` is more precise than post-processing with `RegionMember`.

Comment: @ybeltukov Thanks! Using `RegionFunction` does increase the quality, especially while the mouse is clicked.  `RegionMember` is now used to create the `RegionFunction`, which probably isn't the best idea performance wise, but a nice opportunity to use this v10 function.