# Zooming a portion of a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to zoom/exaggerate a  portion of the following plot for `t` between `1` and `2`, such that the zoomed portion is also within the main plot.

```
x[t_] = Sin[50 t]/t + Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[30 t]/t^2 + Cos[t^2];
P1 = Plot[x[t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
P2 = Plot[y[t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[P2, P1]
```

Please help.

Comment: Define "highlight".

Comment: Echo David's comment about what is meant by highlight

Comment: By highlight, I mean to zoom a particular portion so that it is clearly visible.

Comment: I think this link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100691/magnifying-glass-on-a-plot can help you

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140090/280

Answer (score 4):

```
x[t_] = Sin[50 t]/t + Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[30 t]/t^2 + Cos[t^2];
sub = Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 Epilog -> Inset[sub, Scaled[{.3, .55}], Scaled[{0, 0}], 3], 
 PlotRange -> {-12, 12}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[P2, P1, 
 Epilog -> {Opacity[0.5], Yellow, Rectangle[{1, -2}, {2, 2}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted region is under the plots of x[t] and y[t], so the plots are not covered by the plots like Epilog did.

In:

```
Remove[x, y, t, highlight]
x[t_] = Sin[50 t]/t + Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[30 t]/t^2 + Cos[t^2];
P1 = Plot[x[t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
P2 = Plot[y[t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Red];

HighlightRegion[f1_, f2_, a_, b_] := 
 Module[{t, xyMin, xyMax, highlight, fs},
  fs = {f1, f2};
  xyMin = 
   fs // Map[NMinValue[{#[t], a <= t <= b}, t] &] // {a, Min[#]} &; 
  xyMax = fs // 
     Map[NMaxValue[{#[t], a <= t <= b}, t] &] // {b, Max[#]} &;
  highlight = Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[xyMin, xyMax]}, Axes -> True]
  ]
highlight = HighlightRegion[x, y, 1, 2];
Show[highlight, P2, P1]
```

Out:
[image]