# Lens on a map. Realistic imitation of magnifying glass on images with text and other small features

Tags: graphics, image-processing, physics, image, coordinate-transformation

**UPDATE**: Code from this post was used for video generation here:
[Cinematically moving a lens over images: magnifying glass effect in videos](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3061231)

---

[image]

I am trying to create a magnifying glass effect for images with small text and other features similar to realistic one you can see above. My basic solution is based on an example I saw in docs on [ImageTransformation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTransformation.html) - see Fish Eye effect in Neat Examples section.

```
MG[img_, radius_, pos_, strength_] := Module[
  {transform},
  transform[pt_] := With[
    {
      r = Norm[pt - pos],  (* Distance from the center of the magnifying glass *)
      a = ArcTan @@ (pt - pos)  (* Angle with respect to the center *)
    },
    If[
      r < radius,  (* If the point is inside the magnifying glass *)
      pos + (r/strength) {Cos[a], Sin[a]},  (* Apply the magnifying effect *)
      pt  (* Otherwise, keep the point unchanged *)
    ]
  ];
  (* Highlight the boundary of the magnifying glass using a black circle *)
  HighlightImage[ImageTransformation[img, transform, 
  DataRange -> Full, Padding -> White], {Gray, Circle[pos, radius]}]
];
```

Lets get some test image:

```
testIMG=ImageResize[Rasterize[StringTake[
ExampleData[{"Text","DeclarationOfIndependence"}],5000]],800]
```

And test:

```
MG[testIMG, 150, {200, 200}, 2]
```

[image]

But it is far from good imitation of realistic optical effect. Specifically, nice "flow" features from the page and into the glass at tis edges is not recreated. **Please post your versions, that can be totally different or improvements - the goal is to get best effect close to optical one.** No need to imitate reflectional glaring. The arguments of the function should be at least those I used taking image and lens position, size, and magnification strength.

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8673/5467)

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov, you should introduce the radial distortion. Try to make the reverse correction according to formulas from Software correction chapter of [_this_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)) page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your code you use constant `strength`: `(r/strength)`.

You can change it to depend on `r`:

linearly

```
r/((1 - strength)/radius r + strength)
```

or non-linearly

```
r/(1 + (Sqrt[radius^2 - r^2] (-1 + strength))/radius)
```

I used `strength=2` for the images.

For linear dependence:

[image]

For non-linear dependence:

[image]

The non-linear dependence is more realistic.

Here is another version of non-linlinear dependence that is I think even better:

```
r/((1/(2 (-1 + strength)))(-1 - radius^2 + 
    Sqrt[(radius^2 + (-1 + strength)^2)^2 - 4 r^2 (-1 + strength)^2] +
     strength^2))
```

[image]

Here are depicted dependences of strength `s` on radius `r` for `strength=2` and `radius=5`, the first blue is linear, second orange is ellipsoidal and third green is circular.

[image]

Comment: Wow pretty cool improvement, thank you. How did you get these formulas, especially last one?

Comment: Simply - the curve must contain points `{0,strength}` and `{radius, 1}` (see black dots on my last image), because you want at center when `r=0` strength to be `strength` and at border of the radius when `r=radius` strength `1`. Strength `1` means no magnification at all.

Comment: BTW i think it'd be cool to have publish this at the [The Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository)

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov: If you know how to publish there then do so. I have not published there anything and do not know how to do it.

Comment: It is easy. Less complicated than publishing on this forum. I prefer original authors to publish it because it counts as a publication. Let me know if you'd like to email about the details.